# Issues Transforming to Eye Space

Tags: c++, glsl, shader, transformation, space

I've been trying to get all of my lights into eye space for the GLSL shaders I'm using, but I'm missing something. I have no idea what I'm missing. Here's my shader code, just in case it's causing the problem...

```
varying vec3 normal, lightDir;

uniform vec3 lightPos;

//gl_Normal: Object Space
//gl_Vertex: Object Space
//lightDir: Eye Space

void main()
{
    vec4 vert;
    normal = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;
    vert = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    lightDir = normalize(vec3(vec4(lightPos, 1.0) - vert));

    gl_Position = ftransform();
    gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
}
```

If it isn't that, then it must be the way I'm transforming the light position CPU side, so here's what I'm doing...

```
eye = inverse(camera->climb(root));
glMultMatrixf(value_ptr(eye));
glUniform3fv(sLight, 1, value_ptr(vec3(eye * light->climb(root) * vec4())));
```

Everything else in my program is working perfectly, but there's something I'm not spotting here. NOTE: camera->climb(root) yields the transformation of the camera's scene node in world space. light->climb(root) yields the transformation of the light's scene node in world space.

EDIT: The exact symptoms I'm having are that my light always appears to be at the origin in eye space (in the same location as the camera).

Comment: *camera->climb(root) yields the transformation of the light's scene node in world space.* : Do you mean to say the **camera's** scene node in world space? Or is the light at the same position as the camera?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I'll edit. Funny thing though, the glitch I'm having makes it seem that the light is always at the same position as the camera. I thought for a moment there I might have solved it but no.

Comment: Hmm, your math looks like it should be correct to me. How have you determined that it's not set correctly? What are your symptoms?

Comment: See my above comment. I recently edited it to tell my symptoms. (this would mean the light always appears to be at the origin in eye space).

Comment: Does `vec4()` default to (0,0,0,0) or (0,0,0,1)?

Comment: One of the two. I'll try explicitly choosing vec4(0, 0, 0, 1). Whoa! It certainly did something! My light is going wierd. I'll move the camera a bit.

Comment: Yeah I'm not really sure, that's the only potential issue I see so far. Not sure if it makes a difference, but I think you want w=1 for the origin coordinate (else it becomes a direction).

Comment: It might be working properly now. Let me get the camera moving too. It's working! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move answer from the comment:

The origin coordinate that you multiply to get your light's eye-space position should be vec4(0,0,0,1) instead of vec4(0,0,0,0).

Comment: Waitwait! It's important that you mention the thing about directions versus positions! (If people come here with directions that aren't transforming properly, it could help them alot).